# React-Native Download JSON and Display

Tags: json, react-native

I am trying to download a json file and display them. But the activity state of isLoading is continuous to be true. I cannot see the data. How do I know if the json was even downloaded ? I have tried other tutorials but still cannot get this going. Where did I do wrong ?

```
export default class CategoryScreen extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            isLoading: true,
            dataSource: null,
        }
    }


    componentDidMount(){
        return fetch('https://reactnative.dev/movies.json')
            .then((response) => response.json() )
            .then((responseJson) => {
                this.setState({
                    isLoading: false,
                    dataSource: responseJson.movies,
                })
            })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }


    render() {

        if (this.state.isLoading) {
            return (
                <View>
                    <ActivityIndicator />
                </View>
            )
        } else {

            let movies = this.state.dataSource.map((val, key) => {
                return <View key={key} style={styles.item}>
                    <Text>{val.title}</Text>
                </View>
            });

            return (       

                <View style={styles.container}>
                    {movies}
                </View>
            );
            
        }
    }
} 


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        // flexDirection: 'column',
        // color: '#ffffff',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        color: 'white',
        backgroundColor: '#212121',
      },
  });
```

[image]

Comment: your code is working fine on my side. make sure your device has proper internet connection

Comment: Hi Shammi. Thank you. Are you able to give any comment on the JSON in this link? At the datasource, 
I changed it to dataSource: resposneJson, i received error SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0.
Not sure what is really the probem.

http://xhunterx.ezyro.com/a-cnn.json